# Vaadin Flow custom interface for toggling component visibility without beeing accessible through the DOM when invisible

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

we're currently trying to improve our Interfaces to toggle the visibility of different components of our vaadin UI (14.3.1) based on an authorization check. The goal is to set an Authorization/role to our components as *configuration*, so that based on the currently logged in user the UI knows which components to show and which ones to "hide" without having bulky if-statements in every view of our code.

```
// creation of a button with additional authorization configuration
Button b = new CustomButton("Save").withAuthorization(12345);
```

These might include basic fields, tabs, columns, buttons etc., so that for every Component we have, the interface for visibility toggling based on Authorization is on top of the real component, giving the developer a smoth option for auth checks of components. The abstract custom layer of these components already exists because we're having more custom features on all these components anyways. So this would be a good place for us to add an additional "configuration" for the authorization toggling.

Our first approach was to toggle the components throught vaadin's `setVisible` function, which is kinda nice, but brings out some security issues. When toggling the visibility to false, the items are not exactly removed from the UI, but just hidden and blocked for interaction. That means you can bring these elements back to the UI by just doing some DOM manipulation. The elements might not work properly because the interaction is blocked, but the information can still be shown. For some of our Components it is just not sufficient, because there's some information that should be in no way visible to the user, therefore just setting it to *invisible* is not enough.

An alternative would be to manually check for the authorization before *adding* an element to the UI, which would result in massive amounts of if-statements in all our views.

```
Button b = new Button("Save");
// this would have to be done for every single component that should land in the UI
if(user.hasAuth(12345)){
    add(b);
}
```

So here's my question: how can I adjust or configure the components so that we can create, configure and add them to the UI with the ability to toggle its visibility through a simple flag that cannot be undone/set visible through DOM manipulation? Is there any flag or feature of a component that completely removes the Element from or adds it to the UI based on a simple boolean check that can be changed during runtime from the backend?

Our goal in the background is pretty simple, we just want to define one easy way to toggle elements based on authorization for all our components, so that the developer can be sure everything is handled properly and safely without re-implementing the same logic over and over again.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Flow provides no such mechanism, and I don't think there's any easy way of implementing one based on the available architecture.

I'm afraid you'd have to resort to the alternatives that you've already discovered. Could it be sensible to have a hybrid approach where components without sensitive contents are managed using `setVisible` and then the extra boilerplate with `if (hasAuth(1234)) add(component);` only for sensitive content? Yet another pattern that might be useful in some cases could be to set the content based on permissions, i.e. `holder.setText(hasAuth(1234) ? sensitiveContent : "");`